# Caching and Replay Proxy Server in Deployment

Tags: security, caching, architecture, proxy

I have a logging server that receives data from some stateless clients on a single network (inaccessible from the outside world). I'd like to make sure all logs are eventually received by the server, even if the internet connection goes down.

To do this the easiest solution would be to set up a proxy server, and have the client log to *both* the logging server and the proxy server. The proxy server then tries to log to the logging server, and if it fails it caches the request for later. Something like this:

[image: proxy server architecture]

Notes:

- All requests are idempotent.
- The clients are stateless (logs can not be cached on the clients)
- All parts of the system, except the intermediate "internet" step, are configurable.
- The proxy server does not need to read or modify the data.
- The logging server response is not used by the client.
- I cannot make significant changes to the client or logging server (Cassandra would be great for this application, though).

My questions: is there any off the shelf software that can serve as the proxy? If not, anything to think about when writing this? Are there any concerns with this scheme?

Answer (score 0):

your proxy looks like a simple persistent queue. all you have to do is to add/configure connector to the logging server.

but even without a queue the whole process looks like 2 db queries and and 2 rest calls - you will probably waste more time comparing different products than writing it on your own